# How to get only active list of paired devices through Bluetooth?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am getting the Bluetooth paired by method getBondedDevices(). The method returns all the devices which are already paired.

In the list of paired devices there may be devices where Bluetooth may be turned off or out of range(Not reachable).

My requirement is to get the Bluetooth devices which are active(turned on).

Any one know how to find this,

Please help me.

Comment: it will only return those devices with are bluetooth on--> range -->paired  and are in range...you need not to do something extra for it....

Comment: ..what have your tried so far?